# How can I get PayPal Buyer's mail

Tags: paypal, email

How can I post the PayPal buyer's email to a landing page? I'm not familiar with PayPal API. The Client told me that he has an option to redirect after the transaction to a landing page. I need that email address on that. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "**SetExpressCheckout"** API then you can pass one parameter **"EMAIL"** which corresponds to the buyer's email and will be automatically filled when the buyer reaches to the PayPal checkout page . You can look "SetExpressCheckout" API request parameters [here.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/#id09BHC0UG0RO)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how and where do i use this API? The client has a whole website, what was not created by me. He asked me to send an email for his clients after the purchases. I have been made the sending function, but do not know the adress...

Comment: First you need to check whether you are using the API integration or simple button integration . Can you paste the website here , so that I can tell whether its an button or the API integration ?

Comment: Ok. Then you should refer the below link as it is for button variables and the variable will be "email" . You just need to pass this variable along with the other variables that you are submitting to the PayPal . https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/